# Polymer 1.x: How to remove whitespace from paper-menu inside paper-dialog?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, polymer-1.x

### I want this...

Below is a `paper-dialog` implementation. It contains whitespace at the top and bottom of the dialog element. I want to eliminate the white space.

http://jsbin.com/bupicetoma/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    --paper-menu {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    paper-menu {
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    paper-item:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    paper-item {
      --paper-item: {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
      };
    }
  </style>

  <button on-tap="show">Show</button>

  <paper-dialog id="dia">
    <paper-menu>
      <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Item 3</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-dialog>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
      show: function() {
        this.$.dia.open();
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

### ... to resemble this.

I want the `paper-menu` inside the dialog to look like the following `paper-menu` without any whitespace.

http://jsbin.com/hovayitela/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    --paper-menu {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    paper-menu {
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    paper-item:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    paper-item {
      --paper-item: {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
      };
    }
  </style>

  <paper-menu>
    <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Item 3</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
      show: function() {
        this.$.dia.open();
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS mixin (`--paper-menu`) should be declared inside a rule (it's currently outside any rules). I would move that into the `paper-menu` rule:

```
paper-menu {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fuzutuq/edit?html,output)

FYI, that whitespace is from [`paper-dialog-shared-styles.html`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/blob/master/paper-dialog-shared-styles.html#L55-L61).